# Only allow 'git push heroku master' from the master branch

Tags: macos, git, heroku, git-branch

I recently set up dev/staging/production environment on OSX Lion. I have a git repo with a development and a master branch, and a Heroku instance with master and staging origins.

The basic workflow is to develop in the development branch, merge into master, deploy to staging, then finally deploy to production.

I'd like to prevent Heroku deployments when I'm in any branch that isn't master, or at a minimum display a warning (e.g. "Would you like to continue? y/n").

Is this possible? Is there a git or Heroku feature that facilitates this, or would I need to write a bash script?

Comment: Are you deploying simply via `git push`? If so, not sure you'll be able to get what you want. If you're willing to use a script for deployment, then this is definitely possible.

Comment: Yep, just git push heroku master. Are you saying it won't work from a non-master branch?

Comment: Yes. Posted a link to the documentation as an answer. That said, you can still deploy the master branch while another branch is checked out if that is a concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Heroku [documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying_code):

```
Branches pushed to Heroku other than master will be ignored.
```

Comment: but that's not to say you can't not push branches up to Heroku eg `git push heroku staging:master`  - you just have to push your local branch into the master branch on heroku

Comment: @JohnBeynon This is true. Up to the OP whether or not this is a concern I guess.